# How to overload method with varargs?

Tags: java

I have a service which has overloaded save method. But problem is when I want to call this method with 4 variables it gives compilation error.

```
Incompatible type: String cannnot be converted to Task
```

Is there a way to call first save method without changing its method name?

```
public void save(String message, Object... os) {//first save
    adapter.save(formatMessage(message), os);
}

public void save(String username, Task task, String message, Throwable ex) {//second save
    adapter.save(formatMessage(username, task, message));
}
```

I am calling with 4 variables;

```
myService.save("test", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(),
            Integer.valueOf(request.getContentLength()));
```

Comment: `Object[]` this is an array, not vararg

Comment: @TimCastelijns Edited my question.

Comment: In general this is a usecase for something like `myService.save("test", (Object)request.getMethod(), [...])`. I'm just not perfectly sure if it will work with a vararg.

Comment: @Izruo I am getting : Incompatible type: Object cannnot be converted to Task

Comment: @hellzone Even when doing the explicit cast for all parameters? Otherwise I don't see a way to call the first method.

Comment: what java version are you using? Seems to work with 1.8, see https://ideone.com/yOqbA7

Answer (score 0):

I think your two methods are doing two different things; slight different, but different. And thus: you consider simply using *different* names here!

Keep in mind that overloading should not be used lightly, and the example you are giving does not benefit from it.

And beyond that: you should definitely look into your "naming"; as `os` does actually say ... nothing about those arguments. From a code quality point, I am wondering if it wouldn't be much better to have:

```
public void saveRequestDetails(String message, Request request) {
```

instead of what you are doing right now.

Comment: I don't get why they are doing two different things. Both are saving message object with some additional parameters.

Comment: Well, I disagree, but that is fine. But I put in some updates, maybe they are more helpful.